# How to merge array field values in php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

My array is like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => a
            [hardware_type] => keybord
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => b
            [hardware_type] => mouse
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => a
            [hardware_type] => mouse
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => a
            [hardware_type] => moniter
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] =>b
            [hardware_type] => keyboad
        )

)
```

required out put like this i want only merge hardware type

```
Array(
    [0] => Array

        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => a
            [hardware_type] => keybord, mouse, moniter
        )
[1] => Array
    (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => b
            [hardware_type] => keyboard, mouse
        )

 )
```

Comment: Do you want merge Hardware types for each & every element?

Comment: yes i want merge only Hardware type

Comment: Your example shows that the same ID corresponds to the same name; Any chance there will be an ID corresponds to different names in your real data?

Answer (score 0):

Where `$array` is the input array you described, where `$newarray` is the output array you desire, and assuming every value of `id` has the same `name` as in your example input:

```
$temp = array();

foreach ($array as $item) {
  $temp[$item['id']] = array('id' => $item['id'], 'name' => $item['name']);
  if (empty($newarray[$item['id']]['hardware_type']))
    $temp[$item['id']]['hardware_type'] = $item['hardware_type'];
  else 
    $temp[$item['id']]['hardware_type'] .= ', ' . $item['hardware_type'];
}

$newarray = array_values($temp);
```

If you want the `hardware_type` to be an array instead of a comma-separated list of strings, do this instead:

```
$temp = array();

foreach ($array as $item) {
  $temp[$item['id']] = array('id' => $item['id'], 'name' => $item['name']);
  $temp[$item['id']]['hardware_type'][] = $item['hardware_type'];
}

$newarray = array_values($temp);
```